# Suggestions for building a WordPress survey website with these specific requirements

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm hoping to get some suggestions from the community regarding plugins for a new WordPress site I'm currently scoping. I have looked at a few plugins already but none of them provide the functionality I am looking for. This is why I have decided to ask the community for their input and suggestions. Here are the details:

**Brief Overview:**
The site is essentially a survey website. The site is meant for a single organization to collect details specific to various branches and divisions of the organization.

**Specifics:**
The site needs to have two primary user roles in addition to the admin. These we can call: the Organizer and the Participant roles.

The Organizer role should be able to create new surveys as well as add Participants either directly or via a link sent to the individual participants to register using a front-end registration form. The Organizers should NOT be allowed to see the surveys or the Participants or the results of the Participants of one another.

It would be ideal if the Organizers had their own dashboard which showed statistics and a brief overview of all the surveys they have created with data already collected.
The ability to export and remove results older than x amount of time would be a massive bonus.

The Participants dashboard should show all the surveys they have access to. Some of the surveys are once off while others need to be done daily, weekly and monthly.

**Additional Notes:**
Any suggestions regarding a solve for this scenario would be greatly appreciated. Even if it entails multiple plugins instead of one. Also any out of the box suggestions or ideas are welcome. If you want to provide me with a step by step complete guide I would be more than happy to accept that as well.

**In Closing:**
I do apologize if this post is not 100% in-line with what is meant to be asked and discussed on this site. I really did try and find the correct site to post my question however the WordPress Stack Exchange site tells me to post it on the Stack Overflow site and the Stack Overflow site tells me to post it here. As a result I have posted it on both. Based on the amount and quality of the feedback from each site I will use that as a gauge in the future as to which site I should post these types of questions on.

Thanks everyone and have a great day :)